# java.time.LocalDate and Jython datetime.date

Tags: java, python, scala, jython, jython-2.7

As part of creating a script plugin for Java based application, I have used Jython to allow customization through Python language.

I have a Scala class

```
case class Event(asOfDate: LocalDate, name: String)
```

From Python side, I can have the user to create a new `LocalDate` in order to create a new instance of `Event` class, but not natural for a Python developer to do so.

Is there a way to allow usage of Python's `datetime.date` and implicitly convert it to `LocalDate` back and forth?